# Display the pdf file(stored in google drive) in webview by using google docs

Tags: android, pdf, webview, google-drive-api, google-docs

My pdf file is stored in some website ex: http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf

Now I can't rely on other websites for my app. So

1. I've downloaded the pdf doc
2. uploaded in google drive
3. Got my own link for pdf
4. Trying to open that in `webview` using google docs
5. FAILED

Now the links are as follows

- pdf stored in other website link: "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"
- Sharable link of pdf saved in google drive: "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8e4zX5Y1S0XV0U0UTZJOUVma00"
- If it's preceded with google docs : "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8e4zX5Y1S0XV0U0UTZJOUVma00/view"

Result,

- Other websites may change their url at anytime. Can't rely on it.
- If I use the google drive link alone, then it is opening in web browser not within the app.
- If preceded with google docs, it is not resulting in a pdf doc. I get something like this.

[image]

What should be done so that I can use my own pdf from google drive to open in webview

I've followed [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19119507/2820534), [Stuart Siegler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27908545/2820534), [Samir Mangroliya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382440/2820534) But nothing works.
:(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a WebView, and the link to my pdf stored in google drive is:

```
String myPdfUrl = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fQfqgEmz-AiCpdHEIh7SNwdnAkQFqDQp/view";
```

Don't forget "/view".

And my java code for display:

```
private void displayWebView() {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(myPdfUrl);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(myPdfUrl);
}
```

And add `@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")` above `onCreate()`

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act
```

Comment: We just want to add /view after the sharable link of the pdf file from google drive... Thank u so much

Answer (score 3):

you can view any pdf on the internet using google docs even without downloading it to the device. Here is the sample of how to do it:

```
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Where `pdf` is a string link to your PDF file. So in your case it will be:

```
String pdf = "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right @Vlad. But, I don't want to rely on other website. That's the reason I've opted for 'Google Drive'

Comment: @Prabs, the reason it shows HTML code is that the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8e4zX5Y1S0XV0U0UTZJOUVma00/view is not a PDF anymore. It is an HTML built from the PDF.

Comment: @Prabs, google drive will convert any PDF into HTML, so you'll have to upload it somewhere else, I think

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8e4zX5Y1S0XV0U0UTZJOUVma00/view is a pdf format. but when I join it to google docs, it is in HTML. 'Somewhere else'? you mean by hosting server. I can't go with free hosting servers as they have their own list of issues.

Comment: @Prabs, if you see the source of this page  http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8e4zX5Y1S0XV0U0UTZJOUVma00/view you'll see, that google drive converted your PDF to HTML, and this link does not provide a PDF anymore.

Comment: Yes, I see. is there any other way to host our pdf files

Comment: @Prabs, I don't know such a way since google drive does not give direct links to the stored files.

Answer (score 2):

**Define Url like:**

```
String BASE_URL = "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://drive.google.com/uc?id=";
String PDF_ID = "<Your pdf id from Google drive share link>";
```

**Load in `WebView`:**

```
webview.loadUrl(BASE_URL + PDF_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to follow the answer provided by "Phúc Nghi Lâm." (the 3rd answer.)

If it is not working....

In my situation, there is HTML-result coming. But your WebView's size is 0-width and 0-height.

So you need to reset the LayoutParam by implement the "onPageFinished." Or something else.

(You should be able to get the parent-view of the WebView. So.. 1.Get the size of parent-view. 2.Set the size data into a new LayoutParam. 3. Set the new LayoutParam to the WebView.)

Answer (score -1):

I was suffering from same problem and after a lot of hit and trials, I found a way out.

You need to click on download button of google drive.

as soon as you click it, a new tab will open with a different url, of this type

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B1dndMpNP4zgdlTuMm5rcjFk3TQ&export=download
//test url//

```
String url="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B1dndMpNP4zgdlTuMm5rcjFk3TQ&export=download";
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.progr);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="+url);
```

Comment: will it display or download it to device?

Comment: It will display the pdf in webview