# How to display PDF inside WebView in Android?

Tags: java, android, pdf, webview

I added WebView to Android. It's working fine. But my website contains PDF links. When click on PDF link on web view, it will open via default web browser, not in WebView. I want to display PDF also in WebView. Is there any way to restrict it to open in the same WebView?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display the pdf file(stored in google drive) in webview by using google docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39220941/display-the-pdf-filestored-in-google-drive-in-webview-by-using-google-docs)

Comment: You will get answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296125/5995648)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link should be open in same web view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308904/link-should-be-open-in-same-web-view-in-android)

Comment: @JaswantSingh Actually I don't have pdf link.Only I have web link.Web link works in web view nicely.But it contains pdf links.Those are not opening in web view.That's the problem....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a pdf document into a Webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-document-into-a-webview)

Comment: See this [Link](http://weimenglee.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-tip-displaying-pdf-document.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**You can use Google Docs to open your PDF document and then load the URL of Google Docs using the WebView.**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView=new WebView(MainActivity.this);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    String pdfURL = "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37098169/Course%20Brochures/AND101.pdf";
    webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfURL);

    setContentView(webView);
}

private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            WebView view, String url) {
        return(false);
    }
}
```

like this

[image]

Comment: I don't have pdf link.Only I have web site link...the problem is when click on the pdf link on website,it will open via default browser....

Comment: try to donwload the pdf and then upload it to archieve.org for making it direct link ... then use the code above given by @AndroidGeek....

Answer (score 0):

I found a really simple solution (without google drive viewer etc.). It will open the pdf document in a preview window where the user is able to view and save/share the document:

```
webView.setDownloadListener(DownloadListener { url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength ->
     val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_QUICK_VIEW)
     i.data = Uri.parse(url)
     startActivity(i)
})
```

(Kotlin)